# How do I make my discord bot send a message when a specific user plays a specific game?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to add a code to my bot where it will send a message when a specific user plays a specific game (i.e. Left 4 Dead 2). How do I do that? I don't want any commands anymore.

```
// Game Art Sender //
if (message.channel.id === '573671522116304901') {
  if (msg.includes('!L4D2')) { // THIS is what I want to change.
    message.channel.send('***[MATURE CONTENT]*** **Joining Game:**', {
      files: [
        "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/573671522116304901/573676850920947733/SPOILER_l4d2.png"
      ]
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I actually don't know that much about JavaScript. But there is an answer below that may help.

Comment: @FedericoGrandi everyone is talking about a guild. That's not what I need. What I need is a **game**, not guild.

Comment: You can't just fetch the game the users are playing if you don't know how to get the users: you need to get the `GuildMember` object of the user, so that you can then read its game presence, like in the answers below

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(GuildMember.username === 'Specific_Username_here')
    if(GuildMember.presence.game === 'Specific_Game_here')
        // do whatever here
```

`GuildMember.id` could also be used if you know that user's specific id string. I haven't tested this myself and I'd have rather posted this as a comment, but I don't have that permission yet.

Comment: Great! However, I need help again. How do I send that message to a specific channel?

Comment: **Always use IDs over usernames**, as anyone can change their username. To answer your question, if the channel is in the same guild, you can use `message.guild.channels.get('idHere').send('hey')`. If you don't know the ID, use `find()` and check the name.

Comment: You didn't define `GuildMember`, @Yamcha_Kippur.

Comment: @MinecraftGamerLR This may prove helpful. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome

Answer (score 0):

To send a message to a specific channel, use this:

```
const channel = message.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'CHANNEL_NAME_GOES_HERE')
channel.send("MESSAGE GOES HERE")
```

or

```
const channel = message.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'CHANNEL_NAME_GOES_HERE')
channel.send(VARIABLE_GOES_HERE)
```

Summing it up, your code should be something like this:

```
if(GuildMember.username === 'Specific_Username_here')
    if(GuildMember.presence.game === 'Specific_Game_here') {
        const channel = message.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'CHANNEL_NAME_GOES_HERE)
        channel.send("MESSAGE GOES HERE")
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, ya know. I tried it. Nothing. How about a specific **window**, hmm?

Comment: This does work. I've tried it multiple times, maybe you're not using the correct discord.js version.

Comment: Seriously. How do I do it for a specific window instead?
Also, how do I define `GuildMember`?

Comment: Also, no. `GuildMember` is not what I'm looking for. I'm talking about a **game**, not guild.

Comment: Wait. Where do I place the final code in the script?

Answer (score 0):

So I just figured it out. It was a long journey to figuring this one out.
Here's the code:

```
// Game Detector \\
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
if(newMember.id === '406742915352756235') {
    if(newMember.presence.game.name === 'ROBLOX') { // New Example: ROBLOX
        console.log('ROBLOX detected!');
        client.channels.get('573671522116304901').send('**Joining Game:**', {
            files: [
                "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/567519197052272692/579177282283896842/rblx1.png"
                ]
            });
        }
    }
});
```

However, I need one more problem solved:
[It says "null" when I close the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYPcT.png)

How do I fix this?